# Scala map with function call results in references to the function instead of results

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a list of keys for which I want to fetch data.  The data is fetched via a function call for each key.  I want to end up with a Map of key -> data.  Here's what I've tried:

```
  case class MyDataClass(val1: Int, val2: Boolean)

  def getData(key: String): MyDataClass = {
    // Dummy implementation
    MyDataClass(1, true)
  }

  def getDataMapForKeys(keys: Seq[String]): Map[String, MyDataClass] = {
    val dataMap: Map[String, MyDataClass] =  keys.map((_, getData(_))).toMap
    dataMap
  }
```

This results in a type mismatch error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String => MyDataClass]
 required: Map[String,MyDataClass]
    val dataMap: Map[String, MyDataClass] =  keys.map((_, getData(_))).toMap
```

Why is it setting the values in the resulting Map to instances of the getData() function, rather than its result?  How do I make it actually CALL the getData() function for each key and put the results as the values in the Map?

Comment: `keys.view.map(key => key -> getData(key)).toMap` a little bit more verbose but easy to read and no need to use that damn `_`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gist of the issue is `(_, getData(_)))` is creating a `Tuple` instead of a map entry for each key that is being mapped over. Using `->` creates a `Map` which is what you want.

```
...
val dataMap: Map[String, MyDataClass] =  keys.map(key =>  (key -> getData(key))).toMap
...
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually tried to do something like that previously, but using underscores instead of key =>, but that wasn't working either.  It works when I explicitly give the key a name.

Comment: A map entry is a tuple, all `->` does is create a tuple. - That wasn't the problem, the problem is the way `_` desugars.

Answer (score 3):

The code you wrote is the same as the following statements:

```scala
keys.map((_, getData(_)))

keys.map(x => (x, getData(_)))

keys.map(x => (x, y => getData(y)))
```

This should clarify why you obtain the error.

As suggested in the comments, stay away from `_` unless in simple cases with only one occurrences.